# Magento Wholesale store URL issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I setup the wholesale store using the tutorial as mentioned here: http://tinyurl.com/yeol7ht

Retail store works great but the wholesale (http://mydomain.com/wholesale/) has issues with the URL.

Every link that i click has it like this:

http://mydomain.com/wholesale//wholesale/index.php/customer/account/
http://mydomain.com/wholesale//wholesale/index.php/shop-online.html

Instead of:

http://mydomain.com/wholesale/index.php/customer/account/
http://mydomain.com/wholesale/index.php/shop-online.html

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please tak a look under

admin > configuration > Web ( take a look under url options , secure url , unsecrure url )

or check in database table under database

core_config_data

this can solve your problem

Thanks